# Unit ball in Topological vector space

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, topological-vector-spaces

Let $\left(X, \tau\right)$ be a  topological vector space. What is the definition of the closed unit ball in $X$?

Comment: Everything less than or equal to one (unit of distance)  away ( from something or zero)

Answer (score 7):

You cannot define a ball without a metric (or norm). If we have one, say a metric $d$ that induces $\tau$, we mean $\{x \in X: d(x,0) \le 1\}$.